# Smallest version of a GPS Receiver searched

Tags: gps, tracking-devices

I don't know if this is the right place to ask, but I think it is.

Short background:

I keep losing things temporary. That means I forget my purse at the office (or was it at home?), leave my keys at home(or were they at work?). See? I want something simple to always recover my things .

For this purpose I decided to create a GPS Tracking system. Now, I found a perfectly matching tutorial [here](https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/403#Exp1). But the components are WAY to big for something small as my purse. I haven't found a solution for the power supply yet, but I need [this](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12751) and [this](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9716) way smaller.

I have no problem with recharging the stuff every night or so, but I need a reliable power supply system as well.

Does anyone know if there are components that are so small, and where to get them? How can I manage the power supply?

Comment: Welcome. Are the answers [here](https://iot.stackexchange.com/a/2259/12) relevant to you? While the question is a little different, a lot of the constraints of a small GPS tracker are similar.

Comment: Welcome on board. Stack Exchange has many sites, and maybe this is not the best one to ask this particular question. If I were you, I would ask it at https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/   But, please do come back here for IoT questions :-)

Comment: You will probably find something at [AdaFruit](https://www.adafruit.com/)

Comment: Rather than build your own have you looked at something like Tile (https://www.thetileapp.com/en-us/)

Answer (score 2):

I almost wonder if this is a duplicate of [this question](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/2245/gps-transmitter-that-works-without-mobile-networks/2259#2259) that @Aurora0001 linked.  I would suggest the [LightBug](https://thelightbug.com/) again.

It has got an 8 day battery life, plus solar recharging, if you can leave it attached on the outside of your purse.  It's quite small (53 x 27 x 15mm), transmits to the LightBug servers every 15 minutes.

It works indoors, and can even make a noise if you want it to, to make it easier to locate.  You can go to the LightBug app on your phone to locate it precisely to within a metre.

---

**Disclaimer:**  All this information comes from their website; I haven't actually verified it myself.  :)